# Constructor parameter renamed to arg0 with Proguard/R8

Tags: kotlin, reflection, proguard, android-r8

I am using reflection to read the name of the constructor's parameters. When I enable proguard (`isMinifyEnabled = true`) the parameter name becomes `arg0`, making my reflection fail. I have tried many proguard settings, as I show next.

This is my reflection code:

```
(this::class as KClass<Any>).let { thisClass ->
        thisClass.firstConstructor.parameters.mapNotNull { parameter ->
            parameter.name?.let { name ->
                thisClass.memberProperties.firstOrNull { it.name == name }
            }?.let { property ->
                Argument.from(property, property.get(this), serializers)
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT 1:
I forgot to add the `firstConstructor` extension. The first issue with proguard was that although the constructor was not being obfuscated with the keep rule, the "primary" flag was being removed.

```
private val <T : Any> KClass<T>.firstConstructor: KFunction<T>
get() {
    require(constructors.isNotEmpty()) { "Constructors are obfuscated" }
    require(constructors.size == 1) { "There can only be one constructor in $simpleName" }
    return constructors.first()
}
```

END EDIT 1

The proguard setting that I expected to solve this issue:

```
-keep class * extends my.class.package.name.Destination {
    public <init>(...);
}
```

I have also tried including `public <fields>;` and `public <methods>;`.
I have also tried these settings:

```
-keepparameternames
-keepattributes MethodParameters
-keepattributes Signature
```

Finally, I tried disabling shrinking with `isShrinkResources = false` in gradle and disabling obfuscation with `-dontobfuscate` in proguard, but it still renames my contructor's parameter to `arg0`.

Relevant project versions: kotlin 1.8.0, android gradle 7.2.2, gradle 7.5.1, Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1.

So, **how can I keep the names of the constructor's parameters** so that I can match them with memberProperties?

Comment: With `isMinifyEnabled = false` I receive the proper parameter name. Is this what you ask?

Comment: Kind of. What’s not clear is whether the names are stored in a standard `MethodParameters` attribute or Kotlin’s own metadata. The "primary" flag has to come from Kotlin’s metadata for sure, as the standard attributes do not have such a feature.

Comment: Looking into this I found out something: in java (with or without obfuscation) constructor parameter names obtained through MethodParameters are arg0..argN. So, the fact that we can get the real name with obfuscation disabled seems to be a Kotlin addition. However, when obfuscation is enabled this kotlin addition is lost and it falls back to the Java name.
With this information I still don't know how to solve the issue, though. Do you?

Comment: You have find out the name of the attribute Kotlin uses for this information, to be able to specify the right `-keepattributes` option . E.g. run `javap -v` over the class file (before obfuscation) and look out for obviously named attributes (I’m sure, Kotlin used a recognizable attribute name).

Comment: Please take a look at https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/shrinking-kotlin-libraries-and-applications-using-kotlin-reflection-with-r8-6fe0a0e2d115, especially the section "R8 Kotlin metadata rewriting" which has information on how to keep the Kotlin metadata.